# Interceptor in Flume with syslog data

Tags: interceptor, flume, syslog

Please find below a sample log message that I am receiving from syslog

<159>Apr 15 17:27:31 192.168.100.40 CEF:0|Websense|Security|7.8.1|68|Transaction permitted|1| act=permitted app=http dvc=192.168.100.40 dst=221.135.111.120 dhost=img-d01.moneycontrol.co.in dpt=80 src=172.16.237.89 spt=55016 suser=LDAP://172.17.251.11 OU\=Users,OU\=Migrated,DC\=abc,DC\=com/Sourabh Jain destinationTranslatedPort=38419 rt=1460721451000 in=496 out=6999 requestMethod=GET requestClientApplication=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0 reason=- cs1Label=Policy cs1=role-8**Default cs2Label=DynCat cs2=0 cs3Label=ContentType cs3=image/jpeg cn1Label=DispositionCode cn1=1048 cn2Label=ScanDuration cn2=3 request=http://img-d01.moneycontrol.co.in/news_html_files/wealth-experts/abhim1132661059.jpg

If you observer , there are key values pairs in the data. Is there any way , I can extract values and store the data. I can't use space as seperater as some of the values in key pair contains space 
e.g: 
***suser=LDAP://172.17.251.11 OU\=Users,OU\=Migrated,DC\=abc,DC\=com/Sourabh S Jain***

There are spaces between "Sourabh S Jain"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to solve it using the OR operator .

(suser=-|suser=LDAP://.{1,150}/)